# ¿Podrían darme orientación con esta sintaxis y el uso de "?:"?

Tags: java, operador-ternario

Estuve preguntando por aquí para poder encontrar una respuesta a mi código y la encontré, solo que no la termino de comprender del todo, el código en si separa un string en un array con el uso de un split al cumplir el espaciado (" "), pero aquí se uso un tipo de condicional "?:" al investigarla vi que es igual a un if, entonces mi pregunta es ¿Este código no es redundante? ¿Podrían explicarme exactamente que se supone que realiza el código?, específicamente hablando de porque hay 2 mediciones de length, una en el if y otra en la variable final y el porque se usan esos en esa parte : ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < textoModificado.length; i++)
{ 
    System.out.println("El dato en la posicion " + i + " es: " + textoModificado[i]);
        
    if(textoModificado[i].length() == 4)
    { 
        textoFinal += (i < textoModificado.length - 1 ? ("**** ") : "****");
    }
    else
    {
        textoFinal += (i<textoModificado.length - 1 ? (textoModificado[i] + " ") : textoModificado[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(textoModificado[i].length() == 4){ 
    textoFinal += (i < textoModificado.length - 1 ?("**** "): "****");
 }
else{
    textoFinal += (i < textoModificado.length-1 ? (textoModificado[i]+" "):textoModificado[i]);
 }
```

> ¿Podrían explicarme exactamente que se supone que realiza el código?

Si la condición del if  `textoModificado[i].length() == 4` es verdadera entonces a la variable `textoFinal` se le va a concatenar  un valor que depende de otra condición: si `i < textoModificado.length - 1`, si es verdadera entonces se le agregarán 4 asteriscos que terminan con un espacio `****`  si no se le agregará solo 4 asteriscos `****`.

Si la condición del if es falsa entonces a `textoFinal` se le agregará un valor que depende de la misma condición: si `i < textoModificado.length - 1` si es verdadera esta vez se le agregará `i < textoModificado.length - 1` y si es falsa se le agregará `textoModificado[i]`.

> ¿Este código no es redundante?

El código no es redundante las ramas de salida de las condiciones no se repiten.

> específicamente hablando de porque hay 2 mediciones de length, una en
> el if y otra en la variable final

En el if se usa `textoModificado[i].length()` y en la condición ternaria `?:` se usa `textoModificado.length`. No son el mismo length.

Usar el operador ternario hace más compacto el código, sin usarlo un equivalente sería el siguiente:

```
if (textoModificado[i].length() == 4 && (i < textoModificado.length - 1)) {
    textoFinal += "**** ";
} else if (textoModificado[i].length() == 4 && (i >= textoModificado.length - 1)) {
    textoFinal += "****";
} else if (textoModificado[i].length() != 4 && (i < textoModificado.length - 1)) {
    textoFinal += textoModificado[i] + " ";
} else {
    textoFinal += textoModificado[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**?:** Es un **operador ternario** equivalente a:

```
if
{
}
else
{
}
```

En tu código primero compruebas si el tamaño de la **variable textoModificado** es **4**, de ser cierto entonces dices que si:

```
i < textoModificado.Length - 1
```

es cierto entonces se entra a la parte del **?**, que sería el equivalente al **bloque if** y si es falso a la parte del **:**, que sería el equivalente al **bloque else**.

En la forma clásica sería

```
if(i < textoModificado.Length - 1)
{
     textoFinal += "****"; // Sin espacio al final
}
else
{
    textoFinal += "**** "; // Un espacio al final
}
```

Como ves el uso del **operador ternario** es más elegante y más legible.

Te recomiendo que busques en Internet **operador ternario** en el lenguaje que usas.

Comment: Básicamente es **azúcar sintáctico** y suele compilarse de la misma manera que un `if else`.

Comment: @Mateo no es azucar sintactico, es un operador, como mismo existen operadores aritmeticos(+, -, *, /) esta este que por cierto es el unico operador ternario que existe, el resto es binario o unario, y tengo entendido que se ejecuta mas rapido que un bloque if-else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/758871/13419694

Comment: @Mateo no es azúcar sintáctico

Comment: @eferion el operador ternario es azúcar sintáctico??

Comment: Si lo prefieres puedes usar godbolt para ver que se compilan de la misma manera.